# Why do piping and redirection work differently with here documents?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, pipe, command-history

Combining a redirect with a here document seems logical enough:

```
$ bash > foo <<EOF
echo Hello
EOF

$ less foo
Hello
```

But with a pipe it behaves differently:

```
$ bash | tee foo <<EOF
echo Hello
EOF

$ less foo
echo Hello
```

What's also weird is if you immediately type 'history':

```
$ bash | tee foo <<EOF
echo Hello
EOF
$ history
$ history
1 ...
```

That is, the first command still seems to be inside the newly created bash. 
What's going on? Why does the pipe behave differently?

Comment: Do you claim that redirection transforms `Hello` to lower case `hello` or is that a typo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're redirecting `tee`'s input, not `bash`'s. Use:

```
bash << EOF | tee foo
echo Hello
EOF
```

A few more examples to illustrate how it works:

```
bash << EO1 3<< EO\2 | tee 3<< EO3 foo 4<< EO4
fed (as a deleted temp file open in read-only mode) to bash fd 0
EO1
fed to bash fd 3 without $variable and $(cmd) expansion
EO2
fed to tee fd 3
(not that tee does anything with its fd 3)
EO3
fed to tee fd 4
(see how, like any redirection operator 3<< END can appear anywhere on
the command line (for simple commands at least))
EO4
```

Redirecting compound commands:

```
{ head -n2; wc -l; } << EOF
fed as fd 0 for the whole command group
$(ps -e)
EOF
```

Or:

```
if head -n1; then
  head -n2
fi << EOF
1
2
3
EOF
```

You can reuse the same ending token:

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd << E 3<< E >&2 | 3<< E 4<< E ls -l /proc/self/fd
pipe heredoc> E
pipe heredoc> E
pipe heredoc> E
pipe heredoc> E
total 0
lr-x------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Feb 24 12:50 0 -> /tmp/zshLiVzp3 (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Feb 24 12:50 1 -> /dev/pts/5
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Feb 24 12:50 2 -> /dev/pts/5
lr-x------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Feb 24 12:50 3 -> /tmp/zshFLbQ7T (deleted)
lr-x------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Feb 24 12:50 4 -> /proc/25749/fd/
total 0
lr-x------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Feb 24 12:50 0 -> pipe:[70735808]
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Feb 24 12:50 1 -> /dev/pts/5
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Feb 24 12:50 2 -> /dev/pts/5
lr-x------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Feb 24 12:50 3 -> /tmp/zshL3KBp3 (deleted)
lr-x------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Feb 24 12:50 4 -> /tmp/zshcJjS7T (deleted)
lr-x------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Feb 24 12:50 5 -> /proc/25748/fd/
```

---

As to why the first `history` command is run in that new `bash` in:

```
$ bash | tee foo <<EOF
echo Hello
EOF
$ history
$ history
1 ...
```

That is because `bash` stdin is still the terminal, but its stdout is a dead pipe (at the other end of the pipe, `tee` has redirected its stdin from that delete temp file, so the reading end of that pipe is closed).

`bash` doesn't write its prompt or the echo of what you type on its stdout (the dead pipe), but to the terminal, so that `bash` will let you enter `history` at a first prompt.

However, that `history` (which is a builtin, so executed by the `bash` process, not a child), will write its output to that dead pipe. When doing so, the `bash` process will receive a SIGPIPE signal (since there's no reader) and die.

The next prompt will be issued by the calling shell.

Comment: Ah, I see. Seems obvious now. Is there (out of curiosity) a way of using brackets or something around the first way?

Comment: @SteveBennett `(foo | bar)<file` and `{foo | bar;}<file` are both possible. In that case the redirection is the input for `foo`, not `bar`.

Comment: Whoa, comprehensive answer, thanks very much.

Comment: Incidentally, do you know why you get the other behaviour: being stuck inside the subshell for one command?